# Looping through each li and summing the values inside of a child div

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to loop through each li element and sum the text inside of a child div element with a class of '.listTotalPrice'.

```
<ul id='shoppingList'>
    <li>
        <div class='.listTotalPrice'>$ 598.00</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class='.listTotalPrice'>$ 1,233.30</div
    </li>
</ul
```

Here is my function. 2 problems: 1) It's basically multiplying the value in the first li by the number of list items rather than summing each list item. 2) Any value with a comma, such as 1,200 - it's reading as a 1 instead of 1200. 22,000 would be runderstood as 22, etc.

```
function totalList(){
    var subTotal = 0;

    $( "#shoppingList li" ).each(function(){
        var liTotal = $('.listTotalPrice').text();
        liTotal = liTotal.replace('$ ', '');
        subTotal += parseInt(liTotal);
    });
    alert(subTotal);
};
```

Comment: `$('.listTotalPrice').text()` will always return text of first element in collection. Must target each instance using `this` within `each` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7XS2n/

```
   <ul id='shoppingList'>
   <li>
        <div class='listTotalPrice'>$ 598.00</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class='listTotalPrice'>$ 1,233.30</div>
    </li>
    </ul>

    function totalList(){
    var subTotal = 0;

    jQuery( "#shoppingList li" ).each(function(){
        subTotal +=parseFloat(
            jQuery(this).find('div').text()
            .replace('$ ', '')
            .replace(',',''));

    });
    var subTotal=subTotal.toFixed(2);
    alert(subTotal);
    };
    totalList();
```